# How to assign case to custom object record using trigger?

Tags: after-trigger

**Trigger :**

```
trigger CaseUserAssiginingTrigger on Case (after insert,after update){
//part-1 
   List<ID> ids = new List<ID>();

  for(Case c : Trigger.new){
  if (c.Reason != null) {
      ids.add(c.Id);

      }
  }

//part-2
   //getting all available users 
  List<CaseUser__c> cuser =[SELECT id,Name FROM CaseUser__c WHERE Availability__c = true  ORDER BY Name ASC];


}
```

from the above part one i get the new case id

from the second part i get all the available user records(availability checkbox enabled)

but how can i assign that new case to atleast one available user

thanks

Comment: What's the relationship between `Case` and `CaseUser__c`?

Comment: lookup relationship

Comment: how can i assign new case to the above available users are in ascending order so that new case is added to the first user try like this "RCS" if you have any doubts please share with  me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code: Considering `Case__c` as Lookup field on `CaseUser__c` object

```
trigger CaseUserAssiginingTrigger on Case (after insert,after update){
//part-1 
  List<ID> ids = new List<ID>();

  for(Case c : Trigger.new){
  if (c.Reason != null) {
      ids.add(c.Id);
      }
  }

//part-2
   //getting all available users 
  List<CaseUser__c> cuserUpdateList = new List<CaseUser__c>();
  //Considering Case__c as the Lookup field you can change as per your field name
  for(CaseUser__c caseObj: [SELECT id,Case__c FROM CaseUser__c WHERE Availability__c = true  ORDER BY Name ASC]) {
      if(!ids.isEmpty()) {
         caseObj.Case__c = ids[0];
         cuserUpdateList.add(caseObj);
         //Remove the Case Id from the List once assigned to the CaseUser
         ids.remove(0);
      }
  }
  if(!cuserUpdateList.isEmpty()) {
      update cuserUpdateList;
  }
}
```

Comment: when i try to create a new case i get this error :  System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0: Trigger.CaseUserAssiginingTriggerr: line 16, column 1

Comment: That means your `List<Id> ids` is empty and it doesn't have any Id in that. Check the updated code.

Comment: thank you so much RCS. the new case is updated in CaseUser details page and one thing that case is not added to the Cases as related list in CaseUser custom object please suggest

Comment: Check customization setting for related list.

Comment: that new case is also updated to the related case list in CaseUser Object.please suggest me

Comment: i changed the pagelayout settings but case in not shown in related list